html2canvas 1.4.1 screenshot error element using background-image:data:image/svg+xml;base64,
I use the html2canvas library to capture screenshots by passing in a className and saving the image file as a blob. However, when the image is saved or downloaded, there is an issue with elements that have background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,...) (SVG image), but PNG images are not affected. I am using html2canvas version 1.4.1.
  function captureImg(className) {
        const bannerElement = document.querySelector('.' + className);
        return html2canvas(bannerElement, {
            scale: 2,
            backgroundColor: null,
        }).then(canvas => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                canvas.toBlob(blob => {
                    if (blob) {
                        const file = new File([blob], 'banner-screenshot.png', {
                            type: 'image/png'
                        });
                        resolve(file);
                    } else {
                        reject(new Error('Failed to convert canvas to blob'));
                    }
                }, 'image/png');
            });
        }).finally(() => {

        }).catch(error => {
            console.error('Error capturing the banner:', error);
        });
    }

    function captureImgNow() {
        captureImg('basic-box').then(file =\> {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file_img', file);
            formData.append('error_now', error_now);
            formData.append('user_learn_id', user_learn_id);
            formData.append('lesson_id', lesson_id);
            formData.append('detail_id', detail_id);
            formData.append('type', 'wrong');
            formData.append('max_error', max_error);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/save-user-note-exam-failed',
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('captureImgNow');
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                }
            });
        })
    }

This is the image I want

This is result

This this CSS

I tried dom-to-image, but the speed is quite slow and not suitable for my project.
 <img width="200px" height="200px" style="z-index: 1000; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;" src="<%= item.image_background_gray == null ? item.image_background : item.image_background_gray%>" alt="test">

This is an image test

This is the result test


You can try writing this code
     async function convertSvgUrlToCanvas(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const svgText = await response.text();
    const svgElement = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svgText, 'image/svg+xml').documentElement;
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const img = new Image();

    const svgData = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement))}`;
    img.src = svgData;

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        img.onload = () => {
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            resolve(canvas);
        };
    });
}

async function handleSvgBackgrounds(element) {
    const elements = element.querySelectorAll('*');
    for (const el of elements) {
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
        const backgroundImage = style.getPropertyValue('background-image');

        if (backgroundImage.startsWith('url("data:image/svg+xml')) {
            const urlMatch = backgroundImage.match(/url\("(.+)"\)/);
            if (urlMatch) {
                const svgUrl = urlMatch[1];
                const svgCanvas = await convertSvgUrlToCanvas(svgUrl);

                // Replace the SVG background with the canvas image
                el.style.backgroundImage = `url(${svgCanvas.toDataURL()})`;
            }
        }
    }
}

async function captureImg(className) {
    const bannerElement = document.querySelector('.' + className);
    await handleSvgBackgrounds(bannerElement);

    return html2canvas(bannerElement, {
        scale: 2,
        backgroundColor: null,
    }).then(canvas => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            canvas.toBlob(blob => {
                if (blob) {
                    const file = new File([blob], 'banner-screenshot.png', {
                        type: 'image/png'
                    });
                    resolve(file);
                } else {
                    reject(new Error('Failed to convert canvas to blob'));
                }
            }, 'image/png');
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error capturing the banner:', error);
    });
}

function captureImgNow() {
    captureImg('basic-box').then(file => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file_img', file);
        formData.append('error_now', error_now);
        formData.append('user_learn_id', user_learn_id);
        formData.append('lesson_id', lesson_id);
        formData.append('detail_id', detail_id);
        formData.append('type', 'wrong');
        formData.append('max_error', max_error);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/save-user-note-exam-failed',
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('captureImgNow');
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.error('Error uploading the image:', xhr);
            }
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error in captureImgNow:', error);
    });
}


Unfortunately, in this part:
const svgElements = element.querySelectorAll('[style*="background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,"]');
My URLs are not as short as that. They are called from a server variable, for example:
<div background-image: url('<%= examDt.image ? examDt.image%>>
In my page, there are quite a few variables like this because it’s a game. It’s not feasible to get all SVG elements in this way.

Now you can try!! I updated

It's Great that I added encodeURIComponent into the code. The full code is
const svgData = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement))))}`;
It worked. Thank you very much!
